# Python: fetching urllib3 request headers

Tags: python, urllib3, jaeger, opentracing

We are injecting tracing information into request headers of all the http request calls in our API client library which is implemented based on urllib3

```
def _init_jaeger_tracer():
    '''Jaeger tracer initialization'''
    config = Config(
        config={
            'sampler': {
                'type': 'const',
                'param': 1,
            },
        },
        service_name="session"
        )
    return config.new_tracer()

class APIObject(rest.APIObject):
    '''Class for injecting traces into urllib3 request headers'''
    def __init__(self, configuration):
        print("RESTClientObject child class called####")
        self._tracer = None
        super().__init__(configuration)
        self._tracer = _init_jaeger_tracer()

    # pylint: disable=W0221
    def request(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs):
        lower_method = method.lower()
        with self._tracer.start_active_span('requests.{}'.format(lower_method)) as scope:
            span = scope.span
            span.set_tag(tags.SPAN_KIND, tags.SPAN_KIND_RPC_CLIENT)
            span.set_tag(tags.COMPONENT, 'request')
            span.set_tag(tags.HTTP_METHOD, lower_method)
            span.set_tag(tags.HTTP_URL, url)
            headers = kwargs.setdefault('headers', {})
            self._tracer.inject(span.context, Format.HTTP_HEADERS, headers)
    return r
```

After such implementation, urllib3 request headers look like this,

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
    'User-Agent': 'API-Generator/1.0.0/python', 
    # **
    'uber-trace-id': '30cef3e816482516:1a4fed2c4863b2f6:0:1'
    # **
}
```

Now we have to obtain trace-id from the injected request header.

In python "requests" library we have "response.request.headers" attribute to return request headers

In urllib3 i could not find a way return request headers for further processing

Could any of you share some thoughts

Now from this request headers, we need to fetch the 'uber-trace-id' and its value for further building URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of [`urllib3.response.HTTPResponse`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.response.html#urllib3.response.HTTPResponse) says it's:

> Backwards-compatible with `http.client.HTTPResponse` [...]

That's stdlib class which has [`getheader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse.getheader) method described as:

> Return the value of the header `name`, or `default` if there is no header matching `name`. If there is more than one header with the name name, return all of the values joined by ', '. If `default` is any iterable other than a single string, its elements are similarly returned joined by commas.

Hence in your case it's something like this.

```py
import urllib3

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('GET', 'https://python.org/')
response.getheader('uber-trace-id', 'UNKNOWN')
```

### Update

`urllib3` doesn't have HTTP request object representation. An HTTP request is represented in the formal arguments of [`RequestMethods.request`](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/urllib3.request.html#urllib3.request.RequestMethods.request) . Hence, you need to store the tracing identifier yourself in your `request` override after it was injected by `jaeger_client`. Storing it as an attribute of the response object is probably a good idea:

```py
from jaeger_client.constants import TRACE_ID_HEADER

class APIObject(rest.APIObject):

    def request(self, *args, **kwargs) -> urllib3.response.BaseHTTPResponse:
        ...
        r._request_tracing_id = headers[TRACE_ID_HEADER]
        return r
```

Comment: I suppose response.getheader would give me the response attribute value, but i am interested in request headers